# Grails cannot find plugin provided view after modifying controller

Tags: grails, plugins

I created a grails plugin in which some domain classes, controllers and views were added. After creating the plugin, I imported it in a grails application by using "grails.plugin.location.'...' = '.....'" in BuildConfig.groovy.

Everything is okay when the application starts up. And, everything is nice when online modifying the view GSPs in the plugin.

But, when I modified any controller in the plugin, the grails cannot find the view files corresponding to the modified controller in the plugin. Tomcat reported "HTTP Status 404" error. And, everything becomes okay again after restarting grails.

I am using Grails 1.3.3 and Groovy 1.7.2.

Comment: Sorry, the problem happens after the second time of modifying the controller. The first time is fine. Did anyone meet this situation before? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling, I found it was an unresolved bug. Please refer to the following URL:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5869

In the bug page, there is a workaround reported. You can add annotation for the controller class of your plugin to make everything okay. Following is an example:

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.metadata.GrailsPlugin

@GrailsPlugin(name='...', version='...')

class ... {
     ....
}